# What is the path in the memory for new File("test")

Tags: java

What is the exact location in the memory when we write

```
File file = new File("test");
```

Instead we know that

```
File file = new File("C:\test");
```

will create it in C drive

Comment: It runs correctly, but I can't see the file anywhere!

Comment: It doesn't have to correspond to an actual file. For example, `file.exists()` might return false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you do anything to put it in a different directory or change Java's current working directory, the `File` object corresponds to a logical path underneath

```
System.getProperty("user.dir")
```

However, `File` doesn't necessarily correspond to a file on the file system; creating a `new File(...)` doesn't actually create a file on the file system. For example, you can call

```
file.exists()
```

and that may return `false`.

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](http://ideone.com/QupbHo)

Answer (score 7):

It is gonna be your workspace by default. You can see it with this;

```
System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Answer (score 1):

The default is the workspace of your Java project.
If you somehow want to know where the default is you can show it with the following:

```
file.getAbsolutePath();
```

This returns a String object that you can then use to display in the Console.

See this list for future refrencens:

```
File file = new File("./../eclipse.ini");
file.createNewFile();
System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());// prints "C:\work\java\WS\java-io\.\..\eclipse.ini"
System.out.println(file.getCanonicalPath());// prints "C:\work\java\WS\eclipse.ini"
System.out.println(file.getParent()); // prints  ".\.."
System.out.println(file.getAbsoluteFile().getParent());// prints "C:\work\java\WS\java-io\.\.."
System.out.println(file.getName()); // prints "eclipse.ini"
System.out.println(file.getPath());// prints ".\..\eclipse.ini"
System.out.println(file.isAbsolute());// prints "false"
```

Link to source: [Click here](http://www.studytrails.com/java-io/file-operations.jsp)

Answer (score 1):

### Assumptions

I assume that by in memory, you mean in disk.

### Definitions

There are two types of paths. Quoting the definition from the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)):

- Absolute paths:

> An absolute or full path points to the same location in a file system
>   regardless of the current working directory. To do that, it must
>   contain the root directory.

- and, Relative Paths:

> By contrast, a relative path starts from some given working directory,
>   avoiding the need to provide the full absolute path. A filename can be
>   considered as a relative path based at the current working directory.
>   If the working directory is not the file's parent directory, a file
>   not found error will result if the file is addressed by its name.

In order to help, we need to know which one you need (the absolute path, or the relative one).

### Examples / Answer

For example, if you want to know the absolute path of your `test.txt` file, we need to know your working directory as well as its structure.

Imagining that you have a working directory like the following:

```
MyProject
---- Code
---- ----Main.c
---- Assets
---- ---- MyImage.png
---- Text.txt
```

In windows, it could look something like this:

`C:\User\Aakash\Desktop\Myproject\text.txt`

If you want to know the relative path, we just need to know the structure of your working directory:

`text.txt`

Hope it helps!